# How to read the on-chain program

Tags: anchor, on-chain

How to read on-chain program and also how to fetch idl for it.

Could you please provide the steps with an example?

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch idl from in cli:

`anchor idl fetch <program_id>`

And you can simply use that IDL for anchor web3 sdk.

Comment: Thank you @yacho. Could you please tell me the process on how to read program code that is deployed on-chain?